# Busca em Profundidade com Prolog - como limitar profundidade?

Tags: algoritmo, algoritmo-de-busca, grafo, prolog

Estou implementando uma busca em profundidade em grafos em Prolog, já tenho o seguinte:

```
%arestas:

edge(c4,b4).
edge(b4,b3).
edge(b3,a3).
edge(b3,c3).

%determina que o grafo é nao direcionado
edge(V1, V2) :- edge(V2, V1).

%busca em profundidade
dfsB(Node,Solution) :- dfsB3(Node, [], Solution).
dfsB3(Node, History, [Node|History]) :- goal(Node).

dfsB3(Node,History,Solution) :- sucessor(Node, Node1), not(member(Node1,History)), dfsB3(Node1,[Node|History],Solution).

sucessor(X,Y) :- edge(X,Y). %esta certo?
```

Na `dfs`, `History` é uma lista dos nós que já foram visitados. 
Estou em dúvida se a `sucessor(X,Y)` está implementada corretamente.

E ao rodar uma consulta `dfs(c4,a3)` (que era pra rodar porque tem caminho) o SWI-Prolog fica executando e não termina. Assim, acredito que eu preciso limitar a profundidade da busca... como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Na realidade, ao utilizar `History` e verificar se o nó já faz ou não parte de `History`, você já está limitando a busca e evitando nós repetidos. Não é necessário limitar artificialmente a profundidade (tipo buscar até uma profundidade X arbitrária).

Seu problema é que você usa tanto fatos `edge` para representar seu grafo quanto uma regra `edge` que visita o caminho inverso. E é essa regra que entra num loop infinito, pois nela você não checa o histórico pra ver se um nó já foi visitado ou não. Seria melhor não ter a regra:

```
edge(V1, V2) :- edge(V2, V1). % Causa loop infinito!
```

E sim fazer essa visita em duas direções na relação `sucessor`:

```
sucessor(X,Y) :- edge(X,Y). % sim, esta certo!
sucessor(X,Y) :- edge(Y,X). % faz a simetria aqui
```

Isso deve ser suficiente pra resolver seu problema. Mas se ainda assim quiser saber como limitar a profundidade de busca, sugiro colocar um parâmetro adicional `Profundidade` e verificar se ele é ou não maior que zero antes de continuar a busca:

```
dfsB(Node,Solution) :- dfsB3(Node, [], Solution, 5). % Máximo de 5 níveis de profundidade

dfsB3(_, _, _, 0) :- !, fail. % Falha imediatamente se o nível chegou a zero
dfsB3(Node, History, [Node|History], _) :- goal(Node).
dfsB3(Node,History,Solution,Profundidade) :- 
    sucessor(Node, Node1), 
    not(member(Node1,History)), 
    P1 is Profundidade - 1, % Diminui 1 na profundidade máxima de busca
    dfsB3(Node1,[Node|History],Solution,P1).
```